# Java, скроллинг

Tags: java, swing, awt

Пытаюсь с помощью функции setValue заставить вставать verticalScrollBar в нужное положение, все работает. Но в цикле почему-то нет.

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
JScrollBar verticalScrollBar   = sp.getVerticalScrollBar();
while(i<verticalScrollBar.getMaximum()){
    verticalScrollBar.setValue(verticalScrollBar.getMaximum()-i);
    i=i+20;
    //verticalScrollBar.updateUI();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Может, нужно как то обновлять полосу прокрутки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте устанавливать положение скролла вот так:

```
sp.getViewport().setViewPosition(...);
```

И я рекомендую Вам почитать про создание анимации в Swing.

UPDATE:
Вы что-то делаете не так, вот я не поленился, этот способ - работает:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setVisible(true);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        main.animateScrollDown();
    }

    private final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new SimpleComponent(750,1200));

    private final Timer scrollTimer = new Timer(10, new TimerListener());

    {
        add(scrollPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void animateScrollDown() {
        scrollTimer.start();
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
            Point viewPosition = viewport.getViewPosition();
            viewPosition.y += 1;
            if (viewPosition.y > viewport.getView().getHeight() - viewport.getHeight()){
                scrollTimer.stop();
            } else {
                viewport.setViewPosition(viewPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    private class SimpleComponent extends JComponent{

        Dimension size;

        public SimpleComponent(int width, int height){
            size = new Dimension(width, height);
            setSize(size);
            setMinimumSize(size);
            setPreferredSize(size);
            setMaximumSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawLine(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Результат тот же. Вначале проходит цикл, причем значение .getValue()  меняется как надо, а потом уже обновляет прокрутку

Comment: Обновил ответ, все работает!

Comment: Да, действительно. Вы очень помогли, спасибо большое!